# Using class in another class easily with an example

Tags: php, class

I have a php class that tells time like this (Time.class.php):

```
<?PHP
class Time {
    var $timestamp;
    function timestamp () {
    $this->timestamp = date('YmdHis');
    return $this->timestamp;
    }
}
?>
```

What I want to do is to call this time in a different class such as (Test.class.php):

```
<?PHP
class Test {
    function test (){
    $timestamp = ' '; // <--- the timestamp from the other class
    $hourago = $timestamp - 10000;
    return $hourago;
    }
}
?>
```

I'm new to PHP classes so I didn't understand what I've read on this subject. From what I've read this can be done with global scope (if its called a scope)?? If you could only show me how to use globals or how to solve a problem like this easily I would appreciate it...

Comment: Be careful when manipulating dates like this. You may run in to problems at specific times. For example, what happens when you are in the hour past midnight? Your current timestamp could return something like `20110602001500` which if you treat as an integer (problematic with 32-bits anyway) and subtract 10000 will leave you with a timestamp of `20110601991500`. Now you have 99 as your hour section. Consider working with the UNIX timestamp directly - the number of seconds since `Jan 1, 1970 (00:00:00 GMT)`. You can get this using the `time()` function and format your timestamps using `date()`.

Comment: @Aether thanks a lot, since I never worked on the script overnight I haven't thought of that possibility before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the Time class first, then call the method on that instance.

```
$mytime = new Time();
$timestamp = $mytime->timestamp();
```

Alternately you could look at static class methods.

Answer (score 2):

You `must` use *DEPENDENCI INJECTION*.

You can pass any references objects in the costructor like this:

```
   function test ($yourTimeStamp){
       $timestamp = $yourTimeStamp
       [...]
   }
```

Comment: _You can pass any references objects in the costructor_ that is if both functions are in the same class? is that right?

Comment: @Logan: you can pass any objects whenever you want wherever you want

Comment: Why not pass the whole Time object into the constructor and call the timestamp method there? Makes it more flexible IMHO.